# Empirical Type I error from simulation different from $\alpha$ and changes based on sample size $n$

Tags: statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am simulating LRT based on Chi-squared random variables. I know that the asymptotic distribution of LRT statistic follows chi-squared distribution with $df=$difference of the degrees of freedom under null and alternative hypothesis.

I am simulating the LRT statistics based on sample size($n=4, 8, 12, ...)$ and correlation coefficient $(\rho=0, 0.1, ..., 0.9)$. And for all simulations, the $\alpha$ was set to be 5%.

When I set two parameters of interest to be identical (null) and calculate the ratio of rejections ($nsim=10,000$), I got empirical $\alpha$ ranging from 0.5% to 12%. I tried to see if any of my calculations had error but it seems not. Is there any possible causes for this? And how can I manage this problem?

I was told that I can find empirical type I error $\hat{\alpha}$ and apply chi-square critical value yielding the empirical type I error to be equal to $\alpha=0.05$. For example, in the case of $n=4$ and $\rho=0.1$ critical value $\chi_{df,\alpha}$ from $\alpha$=14% yielded empirical type 1 error 5%. Then can I proceed and use this critical value to calculate statistical power $\beta$?

Comment: "asymptotic distribution of LRT statistic follows chi-squared distribution" is based on large sample. asymptotic means sample size goes to infinity. our sample size = 4. Try sample size = 1000 or more.

Comment: @user158565  I will try that right away. One thing I don't understand is that as I increase my sample size n, the empirical $\alpha$ doesn't seem to converge to $\alpha$(5%) that I se